# Adding into sharepoint list using react js spfx webpart

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, web-parts, spfx, pnp-js

I am using this code in my webpart to insert into the sharepoint list with list name, but moving this code into production environment is creating an issue since its forming the wrong url for inserting into the list, The url in production is
[https://abcportal.sharepoint.com/sites/SolutionBook/SitePages/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Smart%20City%20IAQ%20Demo%20Requests')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName](https://abcportal.sharepoint.com/sites/SolutionBook/SitePages/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(%27Smart%20City%20IAQ%20Demo%20Requests%27)?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName)

But in local environment is working fine it forms this url
https://abcportal.sharepoint.com/sites/solutionbooktest/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Smart City IAQ Demo Requests')/items

In the production environment URL SitePages is coming automatically, how to remove it?

-------Code---------
public insertEmailToList() {

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Smart City IAQ Demo Requests").items.add({
  Title: this.state.Email
}).then(r => {
  this.setState({ ButtonActive: false });
});
```

}

or Is there any way to insert into sharepoint list using URL of the list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish the SPFx context for PnPJs. This can be done in the *onInit()* method of your web part through the *setup()* method imported from **@pnp/core** or **@pnp/sp**.

**Using @pnp/core setup**

```js
import { setup as pnpSetup } from "@pnp/core";

// ...

protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

  return super.onInit().then(_ => {

    // other init code may be present

    pnpSetup({
      spfxContext: this.context
    });
  });
}

// ...
```

**Using @pnp/sp setup**

```js
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

// ...

protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

  return super.onInit().then(_ => {

    // other init code may be present

    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context
    });
  });
}

// ...
```

Refer to [this link](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v2/getting-started/#establish-context) for more details.